# MobileFirst Adapter call timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have a MobileFirst and using Adapter Authentication. Apparently everything works fine. User can log in and do some work...

After a time of inactivity (a day or so), if an user tries to log in again apparently the log in works as expected but any call to a protected adapter method results in a timeout.

I'm calling submitSucess() method on challengeHandler

thanks

Comment: Can't do anything here unless you'll provide server logs and you implementation...

Comment: How can I activate/get server logs?

Comment: They are in your server's log folder. Are you using Studio or a Production server?

Comment: Hi, I'm in a Production Server. Need to ask for access.

Comment: What MobileFirst version are you on?

Comment: Any logs available by now @Daní?

Comment: @IdanAdar not yet!!! It's a weird issue. It seems to be an issue with worklight sessions....

Comment: @Daní, any updates please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. After many proofs we finally could fix this issue. There were some missing header trying to logging in with SiteMinder and after setting the cookiePolice of the worklight adapter to IGNORE_COOKIES if finally worked as expected